# Конфликт денвера и скайпа.

Tags: denwer

При запущенном скайпе не работает Денвер. Насколько я понял, скайп использует порт 80, как и Денвер. Отключил скайп - денвер заработал. Товарищи, в тонкостях настроек не разбираюсь, подскажите как разрешить конфликт портов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В скайпе уберите галочку с "*Использовать порты 80 и 443 в качестве входящих альтернатив*". (**Настройки** > **Дополнительно** > **Соединение**)

Comment: Как все просто!